# Deleting Post Via Jquery Ajax when Submit Form is Pressed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have Below Form 5-10:-

```
<div id="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="9" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="8" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="7" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="6" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="5" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="4" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

AND I HAVE below jquery to perform ajax and delete that particular post, but it is not performing delete.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post").submit(function() {
            var postid = $('#postid').val();
            var unique= $('#unique').val();
            var str = 'unique='+ unique+ '&postid='+ postid;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: str,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#post").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                        if (msg == 'OK')
                        {
                            result = '<div style="color:red;">Something Went Wrong</div><br />';
                        } else {
                            result = msg;
                        }
                        $("#post").html(result);
                    });
                }
            });

            return false;

        });
});
</script>
```

my PHP delete code :-

```
<?php
if($_POST['unique'] === $_SESSION['unique']) {
    $delete = $mysqli->query("DELETE from post where postid='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['postid'])."'");
    echo "DELETED";
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
?>
```

It is not deleting post when submit function is pressed... 
I want to delete that particular postid whenever user submit any particular form...

Comment: you have to use id of div and input boxes unique. Id must be unique throughout page

Comment: you have several controls with id="post"?? you add an eventHandler to your div instead of the form? any good reason for this? did you debug your clientside code? what errorMessage do you get? try some console.log("...") to see what happens ...

Comment: use <div id="post1"> ....<div id="post2">..so on..

Comment: yes. if there is fixed number of forms like 5 forms, then write 5 times. or use loop with counter from 1 to 5.

Comment: @Dolly than does facebook write ajax javascript function for each post user makes...?

Comment: Why do you have seperate forms for each input elements and repeatation of id's.The id must be unique for each input elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the parent divs to have the class name as "post" rather than having same ids for all. Then you can bind all items which having the class "post" to submit function and in the function find each form as source of event and find the child to get the value. See live solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/vendettamit/nn9FV/
Update code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div.post").submit(function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var currForm = e.delegateTarget.firstElementChild;
            var postid = $(currForm).children('#postid').val();
            var unique= $(currForm).children('#unique').val();
            var str = 'unique='+ unique+ '&postid='+ postid;
        console.log(str)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: str,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#post").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                        if (msg == 'OK')
                        {
                            result = '<div style="color:red;">Something Went Wrong</div><br />';
                        } else {
                            result = msg;
                        }
                        $("#post").html(result);
                    });
                }
            });

            return false;

        });
});
```

and your update HTML would look like:

```
<div class="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="9" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div class="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="8" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div class="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="7" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div class="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="6" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div class="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="5" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div class="post">
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('success')" >
    <input id="postid" type="hidden" name="post" value="4" />
    <input id="unique" type="hidden" name="unique" value="<?php echo $unique; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: you jquery works... but it doesnot append success message... i have added loading image just before $.ajax and it keeps on loading... but in network tab of console it shows selected post deleted but it doesnot shows in page.. in page.. there is image of continuous loading..